# How to avoid Jquery parsing/cleaning up on huge ajax page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that requests most of it's content via Ajax. The returned html consists of 2 tables, which I render on the page.
The code I am currently using:

```
    $.post(myUrl, $('form').serialize(), function (data)
    {
        var $data = $(data);
        $('#HeaderIndholdPanel').html($data.find('#GridView1'));
        $('#SvarIndholdPanel').html($data.find('#Table1'));
    }, 'html');
```

It does not get any easier, but does it get faster?
The second table is almost 4 MB, so that explains, why it's slow - both tables must be rendered from one request, can't be split.

However I want to optimize it.
***I know that Jquery parses the html for scripts and other things. And when the table is replaced it cleans the events assigned to the elements.***

**Is there any way I can avoid that?** It's not neseccary in my case.
I know that my html doesn't have any scripts and I don't assign any avents to it.
Should I return JSON instead and pass that to the native 'innerhtml' method?
Or do you have any better ideas?

Comment: A table of 4MB sounds like a lot of rows to render on a single page, unless you're adding images and stuff. It might be useful for you to look into some paginated navigator or infinite scroll. UI wise, the user will not see the entire table at once anyhow.

Comment: you could use innerHTML, but i doubt it'll make as big of a difference as you're probably looking for. A better option would be to have your service respond with data rather than html, and only render a portion of that data at a time. This will both reduce the size of the request you're downloading as well as reduce the size of the DOM being rendered by the browser.

Comment: In my opinion; i think your scenario goes like this; you are loading your data first, and loading that page again with new parameters... So, you are requesting all entities again and again... Check if a request is xmlhttp, and return only a html or file that contains requested data.

Comment: Dumping that much into the dom at once is silly. Users can't digest thousands of rows at a time, your transport time is horrible and browser is being overloaded also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that `$('#id').replaceWith(data)` works much better/faster than `$('#id').html(data)`.

This is because `$('#id').html(data)` takes the time to trace the object before replacing. When you command a simple replace it seems to ignore any existing value(s) and completes a straight swap.
I found this out when trying to swap out a select list that had thousands or options and using an ajax response to filter it.  While watching the code I literally watched it deleted each select option one by one and then re-add it one by one.

Using `.replaceWith(data)`, did a split/quick/1-for-1 replace.

```
$('#HeaderIndholdPanel').replaceWith($data.find('#GridView1'));
$('#SvarIndholdPanel').replaceWith($data.find('#Table1'));
```